# Level of transparency based on similarity between images GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency, background

this is my first post here!

I am working on a fish project - sand goby, that is semi transparent,
see the extent of the fish transparency on different kind of background:
[image: additional images to show the transparency of the fish]
[image]
[image]

I have several images like this:
[image: sand goby on white background]

I would like to use the surrounding white background (to the left of the fish for example) to somehow proportionaly change the level of transparency of pixels within goby fish - where the fish is brighter there should be higher level of transparency, as a value of alpha channel for that pixel.
So if I use the fish png as overlay on other color background the fish would get colored proportionaly in transparent areas

I was researching a bit, and found this 
[How do I create a transparent image that is the diff of two images in gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82171/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-image-that-is-the-diff-of-two-images-in-gimp)

but that results in selecting the portions that are different from background, whereas I want the level of **transparency -alpha channel** in the whole region **based on similarity with given background**, so I could place the png on different background and get similar outcome as in above images of gobies having different coloration on different backgrounds.

**Kind of like having a glass object, and trying to place it on different substrates...**

Is this even possible in GIMP, what kind of tools would you suggest?
I know some coding in openCV, PIL, but not to such extent.

Final goal would be to use the png as a texture for blender 3d model of sand goby.

Any help is highly welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible technique:

- Load the fish layer
- Add a layer above it, fill it with the color of the background,  either:

  - Sample the background with the color picker on a wide radius, and bucket fill your layer
  - Copy/paste a portion of the background and blur it heavily (you can use `Filter>Blur>Pixelize` and use the layer size to average it)
- Set the top layer to `Color erase` mode
- You can put the two layers in their own layer group
- You can insert a background of your choice at the bottom

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! it works quite well!

Comment: @Eager Please consider "accepting" the answer, then. This marks the question as having a satisfactory answer.

Comment: done! did not know how it works exactly